# Grids in tikz taking into account page breaks

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-breaking, grids

The following code creates a numbered grid with Tikz. I would like to adapt the << quadrill >> environments to the page breaks.

Actually a grid can not be split in two parts between two pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,table]{book}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[left=1.8cm,right=1.7cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.7cm,marginparwidth=0.8cm, marginparsep=0.4cm]{geometry}

\definecolor{quadrillgrey}{RGB}{179,182,183}
%Grid
\newcounter{NoQuadrill}
\setcounter{NoQuadrill}{1}

\newcommand{\quadrillseul}[1]{\smallbreak\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,grey]
\draw(0,0) grid (33.4,#1);
\end{tikzpicture}\medbreak}

\newcommand{\quadrill}[1]{\smallbreak\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,quadrillgrey]
\draw(0,0) grid (33.4,#1);
\node[anchor=north west] at (32.8,1.1) {\color{blue}\bfseries\Large{\thesection.\theNoQuadrill}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\refstepcounter{NoQuadrill}
\medbreak}

\newenvironment{Quadrill}[1]{\refstepcounter{NoQuadrill}\quadrill{#1}}{}

\begin{document}
\quadrill{12}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please  explain in more detail what `I would like to adapt the << quadrill >> environments to the page breaks.` means?

Comment: Of course. If there is not enough space at the bottom of a page (numbered n) to contain \quadrill{x}, actually the grid is printed on the page n+1 (with a blank at the end of page n). My workaround is actually the following : create \quadrill{z} and next \quadrill{x-z} with z small enough, but not very optimal...

Comment: To the best of my knowledge spreading `itkzpictures` over two (or more) pages is a nontrivial business. One way to go is to employ `pagebreakbox` that comes with the `adjustbox` package. However, this may split your quadrille in an unfortunate way. (+1 for clarifying the question ;-)

Comment: IIRC, grids are done relative to the origin, which can be anywhere on the page.  Even [overlay, remember picture] puts the origin on the baseline at \begin{tikzpicture}.

Comment: Is it possible to evaluate the space between the calling of \quadrill{...} and the end of the current page ? If it is, it would be easy with "ifthenelse" to split a grid in two grids.